# Sharepoint 2016 Live Chart Script

Tags: script

Does anyone have a code to input into SharePoint to create a Live Chart (Pie,Bar, Line) that receives its data from a SharePoint list. I am a novice code builder and can not seem to find the right one out there that will work.